# list index out of range when I run my python script

Tags: python

IndexError: list index out of range

I keep getting this error when I run my .py :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dfm.py", line 32, in <module>
    sort_files_in_a_folder(mypath)
  File "dfm.py", line 14, in sort_files_in_a_folder
    filetype=file.split('.')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

for this program:

```
def sort_files_in_a_folder(mypath):
    '''
    A function to sort the files in a download folder
    into their respective categories
    '''
    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    file_type_variation_list=[]
    filetype_folder_dict={}
    for file in files:
        filetype=file.split('.')[1]
        if filetype not in file_type_variation_list:
            file_type_variation_list.append(filetype)
            new_folder_name=mypath+'/'+ filetype + '_folder'
            filetype_folder_dict[str(filetype)]=str(new_folder_name)
            if os.path.isdir(new_folder_name)==True:  #folder exists
                continue
            else:
                os.mkdir(new_folder_name)
    for file in files:
        src_path=mypath+'/'+file
        filetype=file.split('.')[1]
        if filetype in filetype_folder_dict.keys():
            dest_path=filetype_folder_dict[str(filetype)]
            shutil.move(src_path,dest_path)
    print(src_path + '>>>' + dest_path)
if __name__=="__main__":
    mypath='/Users/username/Downloads/'
    sort_files_in_a_folder(mypath)
```

I'm not exactly sure how to fix the error. Any ideas?

What i'm trying to achieve is to manage my Downloads folder files whenever there is a new downloaded one, therefore I manage them into different folder by differentiate their type of format

Comment: If `file` doesn't have a `.` in it, then `file.split('.')` will be a list with only one element at index 0, so index 1 is out of bounds.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Without your input we can only guess at the problem, although it seems obvious. Please post the output of `listdir('/Users/username/Downloads/')`. See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that not everything being returned in `files` has a `'.'` in it. To see where your program is having trouble, print `file` right at the beginning of your for loop. Then the file right before the error will be the one that is causing issues, and likely doesn't have a `'.'` in it.